# On SESSION_DESTROY decrease the number of online users in PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple file-system-ed-login (not mysql) just to track number of users who are registered to my website.

I want to know who are all online too.

1. When the browser is closed the session is destroyed automatically.
2. I use a explicit logout command too.
3. I can handle the number of online users on pressing "logout" button, thus by reducing the count in file "nouser.txt" which handles the number of users who are online.

So the thing I want to know is, if the user closes his browser with out pressing "logout", though the session_destroy() clears out the login implicitly, I want to decrease the number of online users in the nouser.txt file

edit 1:
Just like handling onSession_Destroy() on closing the browser.

Comment: have you thought about adding a timestamp to each entry in nouser.txt. then everytime a page loads it updates that user's timestamp and remove any other entries older than 10 minutes

Comment: You can try trapping the onbeforeunload even in the browser and use it to send a quick ajax hit to your server to tell the server that the user's leaving. but this is very unreliable. There is no foolproof method to detect if a browser is being exited without having logged out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the tries Dudes.

I finally realized by searching through various forums' build structure, I get that the number of users who are online is always tracked by the cookies.

So, when a user is logged in (say for a 30-day-scheme), a flag is set in his name for a period of time and is removed after that. So the number of users shown in any forum who are online is always an inaccurate-measure. :)

This was also confirmed by my PHP teacher (my-brain, lol), who says, "As long as the cookie or the session stays on, the user is considered to be online".

But still I had one more problem. How in the hell they track down the user whenever he/she is online in Google, Yahoo, Facebook..

I got the answer for that too. As MARC-B and ROYCHRI said, the sessions are held as long as the browser or browser tab is open and the user is eventually tracked down by a cookie.

phoo..., what a theory man. As I told, I actually solved my own problem ;) and I love doing it.

Once again, thanks for the try guys, remember the theory.

Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to have an AJAX call when the page is closed.

As Marc B suggested in a comment, you can use the onbeforeunload event.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function closeIt()
{
  // Perform your AJAX hit here using your favorite method (jquery or whatever).
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Click here to navigate to 
      www.google.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But ROYCHRI, there is a problem. Consider Google Chrome. I open my website in a single tab, log in and close it, but not the browser. So the session is not destroyed at all i.e if I open the website in a new tab again, still the session is held. So you see, I am still online. 
Now I go back to the same thing. I need something like ON_SESSION_DESTROYED() function.

Comment: Like @Marc said in a comment, there is no foolproof method.  If the user delete his cookies the session will be lost, you will never know.  What you can do is consider that when the user close the tab to your site, he is no longuer « online ».  If he reopen the tab, consider him « online » again.  That would mean another ajax call « onload » of the page.  The internet is stateless.  We have sessions that kind of immitate state but it is not reliable.  That's the way it is! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddies. I think I have to figure it out through a SPECIAL way as I always do :)